# PHPUnit::How can be __construct with protected variables tested?

Tags: phpunit, zend-test

PhpUnit::How can be __construct with protected variables tested?

(not always we should add public method getVal()- soo without add method that return protected variable value)

**Example:**

```
  class Example{
    protected $_val=null;
    function __construct($val){
      $this->_val=md5 ($val);
    }
   }
```

**Edit:**

also exist  problem to test in function that return void

---

**Edit2:**

Example why we need test __construct:

```
class Example{
        protected $_val=null;
       //user write _constract instead __construct
        function _constract($val){
          $this->_val=md5 ($val);
        }

       function getLen($value){
         return strlen($value);
       }
 }

 class ExampleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{
     test_getLen(){
       $ob=new Example();//call to __construct and not to _constract
        $this->assertEquals( $ob->getLen('1234'), 4);
     }
 }
```

test run ok, but Example class "constructor" wasn't created!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main goal of unit testing is to test **interface** By default, you should test only public methods and their behaviour. If it's ok, then your class is OK for external using. But sometimes you need to test protected/private members - then you can use Reflection and [setAccessible() method](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.setaccessible.php)

Comment: 1. also protected method should tested 2.__construct is public method

Comment: [the same method for ReflectionMethod](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.setaccessible.php)

Comment: Also you can read [article from author of PHPUnit](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/881-Testing-Your-Privates.html)

Answer (score 0):

Create a derived class that exposes the value that you want to test.

Comment: this option should exist in phpunit if not this should be added.